# AppleScript returns "missing value" for URLs of some tabs in Safari

Tags: macos, safari, applescript

I periodically save all URLs open in Safari to a file. (Don't want to use browser bookmarks or rely on the app's memory after a crash)
The following code works well but returns "missing value" for some tabs. (Safari 12 in OS 10.13)

```
tell application "Safari"
    set tabList to URL of every tab of every window
end tell
```

The "missing value" result for the tab's URL happens when a background tab goes dormant. The tab title shows the correct value in the background but it does not return the URL. I can activate the dormant tab by bringing it to the front and after the page loads, the proper URL is returned by the script.
Is there a way to return the correct URLs of all tabs without having the script cycle through all the tabs and activating them?

Incidentally, the dormant tabs return the correct values for the names of the tabs using this line of script:

```
set tabList to name of every tab of every window
```

Comment: Is this reproducible with particular URLs or it doesn't matter what the URL is, even with e.g. [https://www.google.com](https://www.google.com)?

Comment: Reproducible with any URL, as long as the tab goes dormant. Not sure how long it takes for a tab to go dormant.